# Nginx returns 500 when NLTK is running with Java 18 in a Python Script

Tags: python, nginx

I have a Python script with Flask API to read a text and identify some Person's Names. To do this, I'm using the NLTK library as follows. The library requires Java, and I installed **Java 18** on the server. **All the configurations are done and it is working when I run Python3 testFile.py**
But it gives **500 internal server error when I run the systemctl service through Nginx**. All the rest of the APIs are working with Nginx and, even this API works without using NLTK in the Nginx. How can I solve this?

I checked the Nginx error log but this 500 error doesn't record in there.

**testFile.py**

```
import nltk
from nltk import tag

st = tag.stanford.StanfordNERTagger('stanford-ner/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz',
                                    'stanford-ner/stanford-ner.jar')

def isValidAddress(text):
    # nltk.download('punkt')

    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    tags = st.tag(tokens)

    for item in tags:
        if item[1] == "PERSON":
            return True

    return False
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
 location / {
            proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:5000;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
}
```

**systemctl service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Autoscale Flask project
After=network.target
[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/root/smartcap-ai
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3.6 /root/smartcap-ai/main.py
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: So your http client returns a 500 code. What logs does your server output?

Comment: Also, your Flask code is missing and `python3 testFile.py` doesn't really run anything

Comment: you didn't show Flask code but all problem is in this file. You could use `logging` to write information which line of code was executed and what you have in variables - this way you can see what can make problem. You can also use `try/except` to catch error and write inforamation in `logging`

Comment: did you run Flask in console/terminal without using `nginx`? It should display error in console/terminal

Comment: @furas Yes, I run Flask in the console without using Nginx and it is perfectly working. I'm receiving 500 only when running in Nginx. And I'll try with try/except. Hopefully it will give the exact error

Comment: @OneCricketeer I checked `/var/log/nginx/error.log` but can't see any error record related to this execution.
And actually, I attached only the related file here. My Flask configurations are in another file

Comment: nginx my run your code with different `Current Working Directory` and code may not find some elements - like folder `stanford-ner` - and you may have to use `/full/path/to/stanford-ner`. You could also put all code in `try/except` to catch error in Python code and write information to file (or using `logging`). This will give more details. You may also try to run flask with `app.debug=True` to see some details in browser.

Comment: You can also use journalctl to check the logs of your systemctl service